# Outlook add-in window does not allow to paste via keyboard shortcut since update office 2013 to 2016

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, vsto, office-interop

Few weeks ago, I took over the development of the Outlook VSTO add-in. The entire view is designed in WPF. Since Office has been updated from 2013 to 2016 they have appeared some troubles with pasting text into a textbox.
I have a button on the Outlook's ribbon in writing email mode, which one display my custom window with two textboxes. When I am focusing on one of textboxes, I can typing there whatever I want. The problem is in case I am trying to paste text. The copied text is pasted into a "To" field in the window in background, even if I am focused on my textbox in my window from my add-in.

Do you know anything about similar problems after Office upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using Windows Forms controls for Office add-ins. Various issues remain in all Office and .NET Framework versions caused by a partial incompatibility of the WPF core and Office GUI.

Or you just may consider customizing the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI). Read more about the UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v%3Doffice.12))